# Generate license information for maven project having dependencies defined under DependencyManagement section

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin, parent-pom, license-maven-plugin

I have a pom file with dependencies mentioned under DependencyManagement section.

How can I generate license information for such dependencies ?

Comment: https://www.mojohaus.org/license-maven-plugin/ give it a try?

Comment: Yes. I tried that, but it only works on direct dependencies and not on dependency management.

Comment: Entries from dependencyManagement are not actual dependencies. Why do you need license information for them?

Comment: We created this pom like a BOM (Maven's Bill of Material) and mentioned all the dependencies in DependencyManagement section. So, wanted to have license info attached to such dependencies as well.